# $P(X_1 =\min\{X_1,X_2\})$ or $P(X_1<X_2)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

$X_i \sim EXP (k_i)$

I found the pdf of $Y=\min\{X_1,X_2\}$:

$$f(y)=(k_1+k_2)e^{-y(k_1+k_2)}$$

I was told to use conditional probability for finding $P(X_1 = \min\{X_1,X_2\})$

Why can't I just use my pdf, and substitute in $x_1$ in place of $y$?

With conditional, would it be:

$P(X_1<X_2) = P(X_1= Y  |  Y=\min\{X_1,X_2\})$ ?

Comment: You have defined $Y=\min\{X_1,X_2\}$, so isn't $P(X_1=Y|Y=\min\{X_1,X_2\})=P(X_1=Y)$?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying, I don't really understand how I should use conditional probability.

Comment: "I was told to use conditional probability for finding P(X1=min{X1,X2})" Who told you that?

Comment: @Did The exercise in the textbook I'm using.

Comment: Then the book is making no sense. Which book?

Comment: @Did It's course notes from class. Why doesn't it make sense to use conditional probability to solve this problem?

Comment: Because the computation of $P(X_1<X_2)$ is quite simple and fully answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=1(X_1\leq X_2)$. Then, because $X_1=\min(X_1,X_2)\iff X_1\leq X_2$, we have:
\begin{align*}
P(X_1\leq X_2)=E(Z)=E[E(Z|X_2)]&=E[P(X_1\leq X_2|X_2)]\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^{x_2}f_{X_1|X_2=x_2}(x_1)dx_1\right)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_2.
\end{align*}
If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then you have $f_{X_1|X_2=x_2}(\cdot)$ is simply $f_{X_1}(\cdot)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The first step is that: $$\mathsf P(X_1<X_2) = \int_0^\infty \mathsf P(X_1<x\mid X_2=x) f_{X_2}(x)\operatorname d x$$

Comment: Unfortunately for this approach, $P(X_1<x,X_2=x)=0$ for every $x$.

Comment: $$\mathsf P(X_1<X_2) = \int_0^\infty \mathsf P(X_1<x\mid X_2=x) f_{X_2}(x)\operatorname d x$$

$$  = \int_0^\infty \mathsf [P(X_1<x,  X_2=x)/ P(X_2=x)] * f_{X_2}(x)  \operatorname d x$$

Because $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent: 
$$  = \int_0^\infty \mathsf [P(X_1<x)*P(X_2=x)/ P(X_2=x)] * f_{X_2}(x)  \operatorname d x$$ 

$$  = \int_0^\infty \mathsf P(X_1<x) * f_{X_2}(x)  \operatorname d x$$

$$  = \int_0^\infty \mathsf (1 − e^{−λ_1x}) * (λ_2e^{−λ_2x})  \operatorname d x$$

^ Does that makes sense?

Comment: @Bob No. Note that $P(X_1<x,X_2=x)/P(X_2=x)=0/0$.

Comment: However, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are *independent* then indeed, $\mathsf P(X_1<x\mid X_2=x)=\mathsf P(X_1<x)$.  Are they independent?  @Bob